# Listen to Events instead of States with Flutter BLOC

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using the Flutter BLOC library (https://pub.dev/packages/bloc)
I know there is a way to "listen to" BLOC states changes (with the listen() function)

```
chatBloc.listen((chatState) async {
      if (chatState is ChatStateInitialized) {
        // do something
      }
    });
```

But is there a way to listen to BLOC events instead ? Just like I would do with a classical StreamController ?
Thanks to all who will be willing to help :-)

Julien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can listen to BLoC events by below code:

```
BlocSupervisor.delegate = MyBlocDelegate();
```

And your **main.dart** similar to below code:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = MyBlocDelegate();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BlocProvider<CounterBLoC>(
        create: (ctx) => CounterBLoC(),
        child: TestBlocWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is your **bloc_delegate.dart** for listen to events of BLoC:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

class MyBlocDelegate extends BlocDelegate {
  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object event) {
    print(event);
    super.onEvent(bloc, event);
  }

  @override
  void onError(Bloc bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print(error);
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    print(transition);
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Taleb. I was also able to achieve that with the new BlocConsumer

Answer (score 2):

*Updated for version 7/8*

### Listening to changes in a bloc

If you need to listen only for one Bloc changes, you can override `void onChange(Change<State> change)` inside the desired Bloc class.

```
enum CounterEvent { increment }

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  CounterBloc() : super(0);

  @override
  Stream<int> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case CounterEvent.increment:
        yield state + 1;
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  void onChange(Change<int> change) {
    print(change);
    super.onChange(change);
  }
}
```

### Listening to multiple bloc changes

If you need to listen changes globally on multiple Blocs, you can use the `BlocObserver` class.

```
class SimpleBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    print('${bloc.runtimeType} $change');
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
    print('${bloc.runtimeType} $transition');
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print('${bloc.runtimeType} $error $stackTrace');
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }
}
```

Then, you need to initialize it.

```
void main() {
  Bloc.observer = SimpleBlocObserver();
  CounterBloc()
    ..add(CounterEvent.increment)
    ..close();
}
```

More info on the [Flutter Bloc library documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts?id=observing-a-bloc).